# Streamlit bar chart conditional and background color

Tags: streamlit

I have the following code that display streamlit bar chart for one of our job.  How do I display RED for error and GREEN for success ?.  Each run tell us how long it took in mins and whether it is successful or not.  'S' = Success, 'F' = Fail.  As you can see, i only able to show all color green.  How do i use `alt.condition` to switch between bar color.

Second question is to how do I set the graph background to WHITE color not following the body background color which is now in lightgray ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'runid': ['983232','98324', '1032019', '1042019',
  '1052019','1062019', '1072019', '1082019',
  '1092019','10102019', '10112019', '10122019',
  '10132019','10142019', '10152019', '10162019'],
  'duration': [5, 30, 3, 10,3.4,6,12,6,3,6,3,1,5,4.3,4,3],
  'results': ['S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','F','S','S','F','S','S','S']
})

c = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='runid', y='duration', tooltip=['runid', 'duration'],
    color=alt.value('#32a852'))

st.altair_chart(c, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'runid': ['983232','98324', '1032019', '1042019',
  '1052019','1062019', '1072019', '1082019',
  '1092019','10102019', '10112019', '10122019',
  '10132019','10142019', '10152019', '10162019'],
  'duration': [5, 30, 3, 10,3.4,6,12,6,3,6,3,1,5,4.3,4,3],
  'results': ['S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','F','S','S','F','S','S','S']
})

c = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x='runid', y='duration', tooltip=['runid', 'duration'],
                                    color=alt.condition(
                                      alt.datum.results == "S",
                                      alt.value("#32a852"),
                                      alt.value("red")
                                    )).configure(background='#FFFFFF')

st.altair_chart(c, use_container_width=True)
```